# Web site mobile version. How to remove scroll and center the content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I am working on this web site http://dev.phenomena.com/joulupotti_mobile and when I view it on my Android phone, the content is not centered and just sits zoomed out on the left corner.

Also when I zoom In the web site, the scroll appears, but it scrolls to an empty space. Why is that?

My questions is, how to make sure the web site is always 100% zoomed and stays in the center without unnecessary scrolls to nowhere.
Thanks!

I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are allowing to zoom to the user and the default behavior from your phone is to zoom out to display all the content in the screen, to prevent this you need the following tag inside your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
```

This will set the width of the window as the size of your device and switch off the zooming

Aside from that I can see the web all centered in my emulator

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ViewPort meta tag :

http://webdev-il.blogspot.com/2011/04/mobile-web-design-viewport-size-vs.html

or

http://learnthemobileweb.com/2009/07/mobile-meta-tags/